# How to update primary key values of first table into foreign keys in the second table (Entity framework code first model)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two model Person and Membership

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
}

public class Membership
{
    public int MembershipId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ProgrammeGroup { get; set; }
    public int Package { get; set; }
}
```

The primary key of Person is assigned as a foreign key to Membership with

```
    public ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
```

I would like to do the db changes in Membership model which are related to the Person model.

Suppose, I wanted to update Membership details for the Person xyz and all the fields are getting updated with below code, but I don't know how to update the primary key of Person as a foreign key to the Membership.

Can someone help me to come out of this?

```
        Membership m = new Membership();

        m.Status = cbStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();
        m.ProgrammeGroup = cbProgramme.SelectedItem.ToString();
        m.Package = Convert.ToInt32(cbPackage.SelectedItem.ToString());
        db.Memberships.Add(m);

        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You have to fetch the `Person` from the database and add the membership to its `Memberships` collection. (This is an insert, by the way, not an update).

Comment: Thanks for your response Arnold. What will the code for this, I know the one way, but it isn't working for me. m.Memberships = new List<Membership> { p };

Comment: Thanks Gert..! I have fetched the Person from database in person object and added to its Memberships collection...

person.Memberships = new List<Membership> { m };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fetched the Person from database in person object and added to its Memberships collection...

```
person.Memberships = new List<Membership> { m };
```